# node.js production settings

Tags: node.js, config, production

I made a small app in node.js for windows,

i followed a few guides and tips and i downloaded the 'config', and 'cross-env" packages.

I added this part to my package.json -

```
"scripts": {
        "start": "cross-env SET NODE_ENV=development& nodemon server.js",
        "qa": "cross-env SET NODE_ENV=qa& nodemon server.js",
        "prod": "cross-env SET NODE_ENV=production& nodemon server.js"
    }
```

I also added 3 json files under the config folder,  default.json, production.json and qa.json.

An example which i am planning to use the config package for is :

```
var config = require('config');
var connectionString = config.get('connectionString');
```

Now i scanned quite a few posts about a solution but nothing seem to help so far, when i am trying to run `"npm prod"` or `"npm qa"` i am getting the following message :

```
F:\MeanApp>npm prod

Usage: npm <command>

where <command> is one of:
    access, adduser, bin, bugs, c, cache, completion, config,
    ddp, dedupe, deprecate, dist-tag, docs, doctor, edit,
    explore, get, help, help-search, i, init, install,
    install-test, it, link, list, ln, login, logout, ls,
    outdated, owner, pack, ping, prefix, profile, prune,
    publish, rb, rebuild, repo, restart, root, run, run-script,
    s, se, search, set, shrinkwrap, star, stars, start, stop, t,
    team, test, token, tst, un, uninstall, unpublish, unstar,
    up, update, v, version, view, whoami

npm <command> -h     quick help on <command>
npm -l           display full usage info
npm help <term>  search for help on <term>
npm help npm     involved overview

Specify configs in the ini-formatted file:
    C:\Users\me\.npmrc
or on the command line via: npm <command> --key value
Config info can be viewed via: npm help config

npm@5.5.1 E:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm
```

So far i failed to figure out the root of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error message is trying to tell you, npm has no such command; custom `scripts` do not directly become npm commands.

Instead, use [npm run](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/run-script) to run a script.

Comment: Thank you, any chance you know what might cause for NODE_ENV to remain undefined after running the script?

Comment: See the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env); you shouldn't have `&`.

Comment: Had a few issues about it but i figured it out, 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47228777/node-js-config-npm-node-config-env