# node.js config npm - NODE_CONFIG_ENV

Tags: node.js, config, production

I am trying to use the config package (npm install config) to be able to use different configurations for different enviromenets.
I am running it on windows 10.

I got 4 files under the config folder : default.json, development.json, production.json and qa.json.

when i am running `SET NODE_ENV=production` for example it applys to it
but `config` still aint taking the info from the right file.

```
var config = require('config');
var port = config.get('appPort');
```

I done some reading and i found out about another value - `NODE_CONFIG_ENV`. 
I done some testing with :

```
console.log('NODE_CONFIG_ENV: ' + config.util.getEnv('NODE_CONFIG_ENV'));
console.log('NODE_ENV: ' + config.util.getEnv('NODE_ENV'));
```

And it seems that `NODE_CONFIG_ENV` is responsible for the problem because it seems that `config` is using it instead to decide which file to choose.

My question is how can i make `config` use `NODE_ENV` again?
Or if it is not possible how can i set `NODE_CONFIG_ENV` instead?

Comment: Since you're setting the environment, you need a way to check for that environment in your code.
Something like this: `if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') { // do something }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a partial solution,

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "SET NODE_CONFIG_ENV=development&&SET NODE_ENV=development&& nodemon server.js",
    "qa": "SET NODE__CONFIG_ENV=qa&&SET NODE_ENV=qa&& node server.js",
    "prod": "SET NODE_CONFIG_ENV=production&&SET NODE_ENV=production&& node server.js",
}
```

I added `NODE_ENV` in case it returns back to using it but overall I still didnt figure out what caused it to use `NODE_CONFIG_ENV` instead of `NODE_ENV`.

Edit: I found the reason! It was because of another npm package called `cross-env` which i used earlier.